# SSRS - Reporting Services Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

For some reason i'm getting the following error on just one report, the URL is as follows:

```
http://server04/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fcMIS%2fgradebookProfileViewv3&rs:Command=Render
```

When I try to run the report it says:

### Reporting Services Error

For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

SQL Server Reporting Services

I've run the same report on the local server machine and it works perfectly.

Comment: Did you "navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors"?

The SSRS Logs are located on your Report Server: %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;
session!ReportServer_0-3!e44!02/28/2014-08:52:09:: e ERROR: Error in getting session data: Invalid or Expired Session: iqr5c045dzejtxepowx4civt
session!ReportServer_0-3!e44!02/28/2014-08:52:09:: i INFO: LoadSnapshot: Item with session: iqr5c045dzejtxepowx4civt, reportPath: , userName: TDA\RDAW not found in the database

Comment: Do you run the report services with SharePoint? If so, do you use Windows integrated authentication? And do other reports work correctly?